# jest test finishes before the mocked firebase function is called and hence fails

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I am trying to use `jest` to test calls to `firebase`. [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) is an online database service offered by Google. I am mocking the `firebase` module like below

```
'use strict';

const firebase = jest.genMockFromModule('firebase');

const ref = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    child: jest.fn(() => {
      return ref
    }),
    update: jest.fn(() => {
      console.log('Called update')
      return Promise.resolve()
    })
  }
})

firebase.initializeApp = jest.fn()
firebase.database = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    ref: ref
  }
})

module.exports = firebase
```

I am only mocking the functions that I need to test at the moment. Below is my test case.

```
it('+++ actionCreator addAlarm', () => {
    const store = mockStore(initialState)
    store.dispatch(ActionCreators.addAlarm(alarm));
    // Make sure that the scheduleNotifications API is called
    expect(scheduleNotifications).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(firebase.initializeApp).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(firebase.database().ref().update).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The last line in the test case is trying to make sure that I am calling the `firebase` `update` function which is mocked.

Below is the console output

```
abcs-MBP-2:GalarmApp abc$ npm test

> GalarmApp@1.0.53 test /Users/abc/Projects/GalarmApp
> jest

 FAIL  __tests__/actionsSpecs.js
  ● >>>A C T I O N --- Test galarm actions:  › +++ actionCreator addAlarm

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called.

      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/actionsSpecs.js:58:52)
      at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
      at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
      at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15

  >>>A C T I O N --- Test galarm actions:
    ✕ +++ actionCreator addAlarm (8ms)
    ✓ +++ actionCreator setConnectionStatus (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        1.989s, estimated 2s
Ran all test suites.
  console.warn node_modules/rn-host-detect/index.js:45
    [SECURITY] node-uuid: crypto not usable, falling back to insecure Math.random()

  console.log __mocks__/firebase.js:11
    Called update
```

The test case is failing on the line where I check that the `update` function is called. If you look down in the console output, you will see that `Called update` console is present which means that the update function is called but it is called after the test case has failed.

This is the `addAlarm` action which is a thunk action

```
const addAlarm = (alarm) =>  (dispatch, getState) => {
  if(alarm.status) {
    NotificationManager.scheduleNotifications(alarm);
  }

  const alarmObjForFirebase = this.createAlarmObjForFirebase(alarm) 
  firebaseRef.update(alarmObjForFirebase)
}
```

The call to `firebase` `update` function is not happening asynchronously as far as I understand.

Please let me know if you have pointers on how I may be able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the problem in my code and posting as a solution for others benefit. The problem is the way the `update` mock was defined. The way it was defined, I was getting a new instance of the `update` mock function every time I will make a call to `firebase.database().ref().update. Since this is a new instance of the mock function, it wouldn't contain any data about`update` function being called in the past.

I needed to change the code as follows

```
const update = jest.fn(() => {
  return Promise.resolve()
})

const ref = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    update: update
  }
})
```

This way, I am not creating new instances of the `update` mock function and I was able to assert that it has been called during the testcase.